# Multiple clients in esocket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming

this time is the problem of **socket programming** in **python**

**Question:** Below is the code of a server for a simple protocol similar to WHOIS.
The client connects  and sends a request, the server processes the request and sends back the answer.

The code works, it is able to handle **multiple clients**. However, there is a problem. Please find it out.

```
1 srv=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
2 srv.bind(('0.0.0.0',4444))
3 srv.listen(1)
4 while True:
5   conn, addr=srv.accept()
6   query=conn.recv(1024)
7   conn.send(process(query))
8   conn.close()
```

**My puzzle:**
I think the problem may be the **conn.close()** should be outside of the while loop, or the line 5 should be placed before the while loop, or maybe there should be a statement between line 6 and 7 like

```
if not query:
   break
```

By the way I don't know how this can solve **multiple clients** as depicted in the question.

Any answers is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you get error message ? show it in question.

Comment: `conn.close()` and `accept()` have to be inside `while`. Outside can be `srv.close()`. First you need `import socket`. You can set bigger queue for waiting clients - ie. `listen(5)`.